# Wordpress hook action

Tags: wordpress

What is the hook for validation on activation and download/upgrade plugin from wordpress ?

for activation, it is used register_activation_hook..Before activate it ( on the process of activating the plugin ) i will do some checking/validation..

If the verification return false, what is the hook for deactivate plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deactivate the plugin, the hook is: [register_deactivation_hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_deactivation_hook)